# Rails: WickedPDF: Page Breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, page-break

In my Ruby (1.9.2) Rails (3.0.x) I would like to render a web page as PDF using wicked_pdf, and I would like to control where the page breaks are. My CSS code to control page breaks is as follows:

```
<style>
  @media print
  {
    h1 {page-break-before:always}
  }
</style>
```

However, when I render the page with [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), it does not separate the document into two pages. Is there something else that I must do to get page breaks with wicked_pdf?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For some reason, the "@media print" didn't quite do it. I just went with

```
.page-break { display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always; }
```

for the CSS rule, and then I stuck the following in  my page for a page break:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

That just worked.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap and .spanX to deal with spacing then that may be causing the page-break-* attributes from working. .spanX in bootstrap uses float which disrupts the effects you want. In this case clear:both; most likely solved that problem for you.

Comment: Any ideas why this works on my OSX but it doesn't in LINUX on production?

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: It might have changed in the last 11 years .

Answer (score 14):

Tried Jay's solution but could not get it to work (maybe a conflict with other css)

I got it to work with this:

```
<p style='page-break-after:always;'></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I discovered something that might help. This was my page break CSS code:

```
.page-break {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

This didn't work because of **TWO** reasons:

**I. In one of the SASS imported file I had this line of code:**

> ```
> html, body
>   overflow-x: hidden !important
> ```

**II. The other problem was bootstrap**

```
@import "bootstrap"
```

It looks like because of the `float: left` in:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
```

the page break is no longer working. So, just add this **after** you import bootstrap.

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: It was the overflow-x for me! I use bootstrap 4, so no floats. Nice find!

Answer (score 4):

None of these solutions worked for me.  I did find a solution that worked for many people in the gem issues here - https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1524

you want to add CSS on the element that needs the page break.  In my case, it was table rows, so I added:

```
tr {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the stylesheet link tag includes media='print" or media='all' if you are using an external stylesheet:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'retailers_pdf',media: 'all' %>
```

or

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'retailers_pdf',media: 'print' %>
```

otherwise wicked_pdf will not pick it up.

Also note that if you are in the middle of a table or div with a border, that the page-break attributes will not work. In this case, it's time to break out jQuery and start splitting things up. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13394466/2016616 has a good snippet for position measurement. I am working on clean and repeatable table-splitting code and will post it when I have finished it.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and what ended up working for me was to make sure that my element with

```
page-break: always;
```

was on the root of the document, seems when its nested inside of other elements, especially ones with height assigned, the declaration gets ignored.

hope this helps someone.