# making a page break when pdf generated with wicked_pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

sample.erb.html

```
<p>Page 1</p1>

<p>Page 2</p2>
```

So, everything after **"Page 1"** I want to print on the 2nd page.

How can I do this?

There's one solution in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835474/1745902) but it didn't work for me.

For example, in case of Prawn, it has a nice feature called **start_new_page**

Answer (score 4):

in your css

```
p{page-break-after: always;}
```

#### Update

After a couple of questions, I will expand my answer and how I use it in my apps.

#### 1 Some times, the wickedpdf helpers doesn't work, so I add an initializer

_config/initializers/wiked_pdf.rb_

```
module WickedPdfHelper
  def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
    sources.collect { |source|
      "<style type='text/css'>#{Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{source}.css")}</style>"
    }.join("\n").gsub(/url\(['"](.+)['"]\)(.+)/,%[url("#{wicked_pdf_image_location("\\1")}")\\2]).html_safe
  end

  def wicked_pdf_image_tag(img, options={})
    image_tag wicked_pdf_image_location(img), options
  end

  def wicked_pdf_image_location(img)
    "file://#{Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', img)}"
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(source)
    "<script type='text/javascript'>#{Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{source}.js").body}</script>"
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
    sources.collect{ |source| wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(source) }.join("\n").html_safe
  end

  WickedPdf.config = {

  }
end
```

#### 2 In application controller create a config method with the general config params

_app/controllers/application_controller.rb_

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def pdf_config
    WickedPdf.config = {
        :wkhtmltopdf => "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf",
        :orientation  => 'Landscape',
        :layout => "pdf.html",
        :footer => {
            :left => "Rectores Lideres Transformadores",
            #:left => "#{Entidad.find(@current_user.entidad).nombre}",
            :right => "#{Time.now}",
            :font_size => 5,
            :center => '[page] de [topage]'
        },
        :disposition => 'attachment'

    }
  end

end
```

#### 3 Create a common layout for all of your pdf files. Here I use my application css in order to maintain the same look and feel of web page in pdf reports, only I have to use the same classes and id's

*app/layouts/pdf.html.erb*

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> ----- HERE YOUR APPLICATION CSS -----
</head>
<div id="content">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 4 Add pdf redirection in your controllers

_app/controllers/users_controller.rb_

```
 def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        pdf_config
        render  :pdf => "filename"
      end
    end
  end
```

#### 5 Now, in your css, choose which html id is the page brake

```
 #brake{page-break-after: always;}
```

Comment: @Adriano Bacha if there's no need to use CSS, try prawn.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I discovered something that might help. This was my page break CSS code:

```
.page-break {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

This didn't work because of **TWO** reasons:

**I. In one of the SASS imported file I had this line of code:**

> ```
> html, body
>   overflow-x: hidden !important
> ```

**II. The other problem was bootstrap**

```
@import "bootstrap"
```

It looks like because of the `float: left` in:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
```

the page break is no longer working. So, just add this **after** you import bootstrap.

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the float: initial on bootstrap columns fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem but none of these answers, like for me, just aren't working:
I gave up on using CSS to fix the page breaks and instead generated 2 pdfs and merged them together and used the resulting file instead, that way there is no possible way for a page break to not exist.

To merge `files`, an array of pdf file names, I used

```
system("pdftk #{files.join(' ')} cat output merged_file_name.pdf")
```

**Update**

I don't remember where I generated 2 pdfs but I did manage to do these page breaks in a single pdf file by manually counting the pixels in the `.html.erb` files.
`<% @pixel_height = 0 %>` and `<% @page_height = 980 %>`. view the pdf as html to see how many pixels each section takes up. Add to `@pixel_height`.

In places a page break would make sense, I check `@pixel_height + 20 >= @page_height` (20 being the number of pixels a `<tr>` took up for most of our pdfs) and rendering a manual page break and resetting `@pixel_height` to `0`. The manual page break closes all the html tags, adds a `0` pixel tall div with a `page-break-after: always`, and opens the html tags again.

I've only had 2 problems with this method:

- If some text in the pdf is too long, it will line-break and throw off the `@pixel_count` causing a automatic page break in an odd spot and a manual page break also in an odd spot
- WickedPdf is slow

To combat these 2 issues, we've been slowly migrating our pdfs to Prawn, specifically Prawn::Table. It is much faster and it calculates the height of each row before it draws the pdf so page breaks are more predictable and consistent

Comment: can you elaborate how you were able to generate multiple files, i am also facing the page-break problem and want to achieve the same result as you did.

Comment: I can't remember where I did this but my guess is something like the following:
```ruby
page1=render_to_string(partial: 'page1.html.erb')
page2=render_to_string(partial: 'page2.html.erb')
pdf1 = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(page1)
pdf2 = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(page2)
files = ["#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/#{SecureRandom.hex(20)}.pdf"]
File.open(files[0], 'wb+') do |f|
  f << pdf
  f.rewind
end
files << "#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/#{SecureRandom.hex(20)}.pdf"
File.open(files[1], 'wb+') do |f|
  f << pdf
  f.rewind
end
```
then call the merge from the answer

Comment: @ZainNazirButt I've added a sample in the comments and I've updated my answer to explain what we did so we could use 1 pdf

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One quick method is to use below HTML:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
From this line onwards HTML Content will come in next page
```