# Rails wiked_pdf page breaks not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wicked-pdf

I have a Rails 3.2 app using Bootstrap and Wicked_pdf. I'm trying to page break the pdf after each `@costproject`.

Gems:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

I read this post: [Rails WickedPDF Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806943/rails-wickedpdf-page-breaks)

So, I tried it.

This is in my CSS:

```
.page-break {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  page-break-after:always;
}
```

And this is in projects.pdf.erb:

```
<% @costprojects.each do |costproject| %>
    <div class="page-break"></div>
    <div id="pdfbody">
      <table class="table table-striped">
...
```

But, the page breaks don't happen.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to open your HTML page with these CSS rules in Google Chrome and open it in Print Preview (File -> Print...). Do you see page breaks in this case?

Comment: I corrected my post.  It's not a view (HTML), it's a pdf.erb

Comment: Yes, I understand it. Save it to HTML (because you generate HTML markup) and open in Google Chrome as I described above.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.  I tried the url `...costprojects/viewprojects.html`, but I get missing template.

Comment: Just temporary rename `projects.pdf.erb` to `projects.html.erb` and open it in browser use URL correspond to this controller action (you can check URL path use `rake routes` command) i.e. `http://localhost:3000/projects`. The main target is try to detect side of problem i.e. is this CSS problem or WickedPDF generator?

Comment: There is no page break when viewing as html.

Comment: So, seems like problem with CSS. Open [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#dom) and check that your `.page-break` CSS rule is applied to `div` elements.

Comment: "There is no page break when viewing as html." -  you are viewing it in Chrome **Print** Preview. Right?

Comment: The page breaks work if I change it to html and use Chrome print preview.

Comment: ok, this is mean that the problem on the WickedPDF side. Now, need to check how you installed `wkhtmltopdf` binary. Requires your Gemfile.

Comment: I updated my questions to show the gems used.

Comment: ok, I am using the same gems and they make page breaks. The `wkhtmltopdf` gem has Qt Webkit patches. But which versions are you using? Try to specify these versions: `wkhtmltopdf-binary:0.9.9.1`, `wicked_pdf:0.9.6'

Comment: Installing wicked_pdf 0.9.6 (was 0.11.0)
Using will_paginate 3.0.4
Installing wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.9.9.1 (was 0.9.9.3)
Still no pagination!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of different approaches.

Placing this code in the viewprojects.pdf.erb worked for me:

```
    <p style='page-break-after:always;'></p>
```