# How to make pdf continuous in wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I want to have no page break in wicked_pdf. How can I achieve that?
I tried using

```
div.no-page-break{
    page-break-before: avoid !important;
  }
```

But it didn't work.
Is there a way I can make the pdf continuous?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: WickedPDF: Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806943/rails-wickedpdf-page-breaks)

Comment: This is just the opposite of what I want. I don't want any page break in my pdf. I want it to be continuous.